# Hive SQL - Retrieve distinct values for a column existing in a date range

Tags: sql, date, filter, hive, range

I have a table in Hive as follows:

```
|attribute | start_date | end_date   | 
|----------+------------+------------+ 
| x        | 10-01-2014 | 03-31-2015 | 
| x        | 04-01-2015 | 09-30-2015 | 
| x        | 10-01-2015 | 03-31-2016 |
| x        | 04-01-2016 | 09-30-2016 |
| y        | 10-01-2015 | 03-31-2016 | 
| y        | 04-01-2016 | 09-30-2015 |
```

I want to get a distinct list of only all attributes that have occured between 10-01-2014 and 09-30-2016 but they must have a start date in each of (10-01-2014, 04-01-2015, 10-01-2015, 04-01-2016).

I tried:

```
select distinct(attribute),min(start_date) ,max(end_date) 
from table 
where 
    max(end_date) >='03-31-2016' 
    and min(effective_start_date) <='2015-01-01'
```

but that doesn't prevent any gaps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a table with the expected output. Why do you have `min()` and `max()` functions in your query? What do you mean by "must have a start date in each of"? Do you mean a sequence of overlapping `(start_date, end_date)` rows? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select attribute
from t
where startdate in ('10-01-2014', '04-01-2015', '10-01-2015', '04-01-2016')
having count(distinct date) = 4;
```

I recommend that you store and refer to your dates using ISO standard formats -- '2014-10-01' -- but I've left the dates in the format you have.